# "To separate" in time context

Tags: vocabulary

I've just had a discussion about using "to separate" when relating to events in time.

A colleague of mine used the word to describe that an event occurred between two other events while the events aren't necessarily continuous. For example, he'd say "Monday and Friday is separated by Wednesday".

I think that the separator should be "thicker" to fill the gap between the two endpoints fully. So I'd say "Wednesday is between Monday and Friday" or "Monday is separated from Friday by Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday".

Which explanation sounds better? Would you use other words to describe that something happens after something else has already ended and the next thing hasn't started yet?

Answer (score 1):

If the item that separates is being emphasized, it can be used in this way. For example, I could say, "my home in the Midwest US is separated from Europe by the Atlantic Ocean." In fact, there's a lot of land between us too, and some mountains as well, but I'm pointing out the fact that the ocean is the biggest obstacle between us.

Perhaps your colleagues are referring to Wednesday fancifully as though it were an obstacle or wall between two locations, making it impossible to get to Friday without going through the boredom of Wednesday. Office small talk often consists of different metaphors for the weekdays, since it's something everyone has in common.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, in this case, that "separate," used in this context, implies that you're listing all the things that separate those two days, so saying that Monday and Friday are separated by Wednesday is incorrect usage. Either of your suggestions would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I would say in a less discrete context, your colleague's approach can work quite well.  For example:

> Lisa and her great-great-grandmother grew up in the same small town, separated by two world wars, a depression, and decades of change.

I agree, though: your example using weekdays is pretty jarring.

Answer (score 0):

The word **interpose** suggests a position between things that may not comprise the entire distance, as is commonly used in chess:

"The pawn was interposed between the two queens."

Physical distance is often implied, but **interpose** can also be used figuratively, as in:

"Fleet medical care is not only concerned with the same problems as those encountered in civilian medicine, but must also address the special and unique circumstances interposed by Navy and Marine Corps operational environments." --U.S. Navy Medicine, January 1974, p. 15

Thus, to my ear it seems fine in the context of time:

"Monday and Friday are interposed by Wednesday."